# Xamarin Forms Span preserve white space

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

How do I reserve a white space in a Formatted Text Label in Xamarin Forms I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
            <Label FontSize="Medium">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span xml:space="preserve">On PO: </Span>
                        <Span xml:space="preserve"> </Span>
                        <Span FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Qty}"/>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
```

I get this error

`Error Position 22:35. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'space', or mismatching type between value and property.`

Comment: You want a to render a blank white space?

Comment: Yes as you can see the label has 3 spans currently there is no space between the spans

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the text property of the span to give space.

```
 <Label FontSize="Medium">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="On PO: "/>
                    <Span Text=" "/>
                    <Span FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Qty}"/>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
 </Label>
```

Comment: I found that any leading/trailing non-breaking spaces ("&#160;") specified within the <Span> tags _get removed_ - this solution works nicely.